# script to detect db2 deadlocks

Tags: bash, scripting, db2

i'm trying to make script which will check if new deadlocks are created since last script run, if no new deadlock since last run it should print 0 if new deadlocks are created then it should print number

```
     #DB profile
     . /db2/tdb_inst/archinst/sqllib/db2profile;
     #variable to get current deadlock count
     a=`db2 get snapshot for all on archprd |grep Deadlock|head -1|awk '{print $4}'`
     #variable to get last deadlock count
     b=`cat /home/dbmon/script/darch`

     #need your help to do below math in script
     #  if a$-b$ = 0  print 0 if a$-b$ > 0 print number 

     #after print export current deadlock count to darch file
     echo $a > /home/dbmon/script/darch
```

TIA
tnt5273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need your help to do below math in script
>
> if a$-b$ = 0  print 0 if a$-b$ > 0 print number

You can say:

```
(( a - b )) && echo $(( a - b )) || echo 0
```

This would print `0` if `a = b` else print `a - b`.

---

Actually, even the following should suffice:

```
echo $(( a - b ))
```

Comment: thx devnull easy when you know it,well time for beer you are invited...:)